# Plotting pandas groupby results

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very simple data set:

```
Customer    Amount
A           1.25
B           2
C           1
A           5
D           2
B           10
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
Customer Amount  Number_of_transactions
A        6.25    2
B        12      2
C        1       1
D        1       2
```

The way I solved is to add another column where all values are 1 and then use df.groupby('Customer').

1. Is there a more efficient way to do that?
2. I would need to plot the distribution of number_of_transactions and distribution of amounts. Whenever I try to do that, I get key error (I assume because of groupby). Can someone point to the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by distribution? Two histograms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> df['Number_of_transactions'] = 1
>>> df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Customer', 
                         values=['Amount', 'Number_of_transactions'],
                         aggfunc=np.sum)\
            .reset_index()                  # reset_index is optional
>>> df1

Out[21]:
    Customer    Amount  Number_of_transactions
0   A           6.25    2
1   B           12.00   2
2   C           1.00    1
3   D           2.00    1
```

For the plots just do:

```
>>> df1.hist(bin=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want as a plot, but for the first part, you can do this :

```
new_df = pd.concat([df.groupby(df.Customer).Amount.sum(),
                    df.Customer.value_counts()], axis=1)

new_df.columns = ["Amounts","Number_of_transactions"]
```

and then if you can have a bar plot with :

```
new_df.plot(kind="bar")
```

or if you wan't a histogram :

```
new_df.hist()
```